# Find the pdf of T = X + Y

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

Let (X,Y) be a random point chosen uniformly on region R = {(x,y) : |x| + |y| <= 1}. I need to find the pdf of T = X + Y.

I know the joint density is just equal to 1/(area) = fxy(x,y) = 1/2 for |x| + |y| <= 1 and 0 otherwise

i also calculated the marginal densities where fx(x,y)=1-|x| and similarly for fy(x,y)=1-|y| for both x and y between -1 and 1

can someone please help me now find pdf of T = X + Y. i dont know how to go about this.

alright so now i understand i should use the convolution integral: so i should use..

$$f_T(t)=\int_{S_X}f_X(x)f_Y(t-x)\,dx=\int_{|x|-1}^{1-|x|}(1-|x|)f_Y(t-x)dx$$

can someone help me from here? i cant do the $$f_Y(t-x)$$ part.. and now that i think about this i dont even know if my integral bounds are correct.

Comment: One way to approach this is to find the cumulative distribution function (cdf): $F_T(t)=P(T\le t)$.  Then the pdf is the derivative of the cdf.

Comment: can you numerically walk me through this

Comment: @paw88789 i've tried a bit more of problem, i really need your help

Answer (score 2):

To determine the cdf $F_T(t)=P(T\le t)$, I would proceed geometrically.  Points $(X,Y)$ come from a square with corners at $(1,0), (0,1), (-1,0), (0,-1)$.  To find $F_T(t)$, draw the line $X+Y=t$ and note it is parallel to two of the sides of the square.  $F_T(t)$ is the area inside the square to the left of the line.  Since the line is parallel to the side of the square, the probability should accumulate at a constant rate while the line passes through the square.

So I think:

$$F_T(t)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} 0&\mbox{if}&t<-1\\\frac12 t+\frac12&\mbox{if}&-1\le t\le 1 \\ 1&\mbox{if}&t>1 \end{array} \right.$$

Answer (score 0):

So the convolution integral is:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}(1-|x|)(1-|T-x|)dx$$

Now you can simply calculate this integral:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}(1-|x|)(1-|T-x|)dx=\int_{-1}^{1}1dx+\int_{-1}^{1}|x|dx+\int_{-1}^{1}|T-x|dx+\int_{-1}^{1}|Tx-x^2|1dx$$

First two are easy: $\int_{-1}^{1}1dx=2$, $\int_{-1}^{1}|x|dx=1$.

Third (you can eliminate $|\cdot|$ dividing integral into two integral):

$$\int_{-1}^{1}|T-x|dx=\int_{-1}^{T}T-xdx+\int_{T}^{1}x-Tdx$$

The same with fourth integral($x(T-x)>0$ when $x \in [0,T]$ for $T\geq 0$)

$$\int_{-1}^{1}|x(T-x)|dx=\int_{-1}^{0}-x(T-x)dx+\int_{0}^{T}x(T-x)dx+\int_{T}^{1}-x(T-x)dx$$

You can do similar thing when $T<0$.

Comment: thank you! i would have never known how to do any of that. i dont know what you mean i can do similar when T<0. also how do i organize all of this into a pdf so i can show all my bounds for T

Comment: When $T<0$ then $x(T-x) \geq 0$ when $x \in [T,0]$ (not in $[0,T]$). So in last line integral $\int_{0}^{T}x(T-x)dx$ should be changed to $\int_{T}^{0}x(T-x)dx$, $\int_{-1}^{0}-x(T-x)dx$ to $\int_{-1}^{T}-x(T-x)dx$ and $\int_{T}^{1}-x(T-x)dx$ to $\int_{0}^{1}-x(T-x)dx$.

Comment: should i solve each of those integrals now to get my values for $$F_T(t)$$

Comment: Yes. But you can note that $(Tx-\frac{x^2}{2})'=T-x$ and $(\frac{Tx^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3})'=x(T-x)$, so it's easy.

Comment: this still isnt easy for me.. there's too many integrals i cant organize this. i solved for each integral.. i know the bounds on which those exist.. can someone just help organize this